# iTunes Connect upload build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm very unexperienced with iTunes Connect and I have an app in development which I want to upload to iTunes Connect, so that I can deploy it to my TestFlight internal testers. I used Application Loader to upload my archive but got this error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.***.*** [Payload/***.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."
```

That sounds like I was wanting to upload the app to the AppStore but I only want to upload the development build. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any app uploaded to iTunesConnect, whether you intend to release it or only test it via TestFlight must be a release build signed for distribution. use the "archive" command in Xcode

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used the Xcode command Product -> Archive and exported the .ipa file for Application Loader. So do I have to create a Distribution Certificate?

Comment: No, Xcode should have managed that for you if you let it.

Comment: But if Xcode managed it, I shouldn't get that error right? What do you mean with "if you let it"?

Comment: Xcode would have asked you which signing identity you wanted to use. If you use "Xcode Managed Profile" with your team signing identity it should be all automatic. If you selected a specific profile then it may not work.

Comment: Yes I habe used "Xcode Managed Profile". Any ideas how to fix the error?

Comment: When you exported the IPA file, which option did you select?  It should be the first option - "Save for iOS App Store deployment"

Comment: Ah ok I selected "Save for iOS development". So what is that then good for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143444/discussion-between-paulw11-and-codey).

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you make Provisioning Profile Development or Distributation that is not correct when you upload your build on testflight. If you want to upload your build on testflight than make Provisioning Profile with adhoc or apple store certificates. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes Thank you for your answer. The problem was that I selected "Save for Development Deployment" and not for AppStore.